# PyCharm quit unexpectedly on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, pycharm

PyCharm closes and sometimes macbook restarts while running my python script on it. The script runs for a while and suddenly I get the following error:

PyCharm quit unexpectedly

Problem details and system configuration:

[image]

How to solve this issue please? Thank you

PS: the error message is too long with details so I have just added the initial part which I think should be enough but I can add all of it if required.

Comment: Looks like a graphics driver crash which means that you should report it to Apple & to JetBrains. There's nothing else you can do about it probably. Any other kernel extensions installed? Are they mentioned in the report?

Comment: Thank you. I don't think any other kernel extension is installed and there's nothing as such mentioned either in the report